# Calling a method with a string and input()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm brushing up on my Python and I'm a little confused about something, the following code does not work as intended:

```
def a():
    print "called a"

def b():
    print "called b"

dispatch = {'go':a, 'stop':b}
dispatch[input()]()
```

When I type the word *go* into the console, I get "NameError: name 'go' is not defined", but when I type 'go' (with the quotes) it works fine. Is input() not returning a string? And if not, then shouldn't using str() convert the input to a string?

When I change the code to:

```
dispatch[(str(input())]()
```

I still get the same behaviour.

note: I'm using Python2.7 if it makes a difference.

Sorry if this is obvious, it's been a few years since I've used Python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` in Python 2.7 is equivalent to:

```
eval(raw_input())
```

Hence, you should use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) in python 2.7 to avoid such errors, as it will not try to `eval`uate the input given.

Because you add in quotation marks, Python interprets this as a string.

Also, note that `raw_input()` will return a string, so there will be no point in calling `str()` around it.

---

Note that in Python 3, `input()` acts like `raw_input()` did in Python 2.7

Comment: I read a list of the more 'notable' changes between 2.X and 3.X but this one wasn't listed, thanks!

Comment: @NickBoudreau Hmm, where abouts was this? There's a great list at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) if you wish to check it out :)

Comment: I can't remember the site, it was just someone's blog I think, but I wrote down the changes they listed: strings are now unicode, print is a function not a statement, range is removed and replaced with xrange, division of integers results in a float and all classes are now new-style. Thanks for the link, very useful!

Answer (score 2):

You want `raw_input()`. `input()` evaluates the user's input as Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_input()`. `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, so when you type go without quotes, python tries to eval go and fails. With the quotes, it eval's the string (ie. returns it) which will work to index your dict.

raw_input will work in every case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
def go():
    print "called a"


def stop():
    print "called b"

input()()  # Equivalent to eval(raw_input())()
# OR
my_function = input()
my_function()  # Might be easier to read

# Another way of doing it:

val = raw_input()
globals()[val]()
```